# Connect to a Windows Authentication SQL server in SQL Server Authentication mode?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, authentication

Is it possible to connect to a SQL server in SQL Server Authentication if the server has been installed with Windows Authentication?

Comment: it doesn't matter how SQL server was "installed", you can switch the authentication method at any time.

Answer (score 2):

No. You'd need to be in "mixed mode" which is both SQL and Windows Authentication